# How do I get the text to show after adding styling to AlertDialog in Android?

Tags: android

I've added a theme to my Android(API 15) app but it has had the unexpected consequence of hiding the text in my dialogs.

Here's how it looks without styling

[image: Without styling]

And here's how it looks with styling added

[image: With styling]

Here's how I build the dialog:

```
private void showWarning() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Warning");
    builder.setMessage("Information shown might be wrong.");
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            dialogs.remove(DIALOG_WARNING);
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Quit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            TravelHealthActivity.mInstance.deleteDatabase("TravelHealth");
            finish();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dlg = builder.create();
    dlg.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialogs.put(DIALOG_WARNING, dlg);
    dlg.show();
}
```

Here's my complete style.xml, [I've been trying to get rid of the background for the spinner dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703233/style-android-spinner/), hence a whole bunch of background stuff. I'm new to styling so I wasn't sure what's relevant and could be causing the text to dissapear.

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<style name="appcin" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/spinnerStyle</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerDropDownItem</item> -->
    <item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/checkboxStyle</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownStyler</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSpinnerStyle">@style/DropDownStyle</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@style/DropDownStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="layout">
    <item name="android:padding">10dip</item>
</style>
<style name="title" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#993399</item>
</style>
<style name="text" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#111111</item>
</style>
<style name="textview" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#993399</item>
    <item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
<style name="edittext" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#111111</item>
</style>
<style name="button" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#111111</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/rect_white</item>
    <item name="android:padding">10dip</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">10dip</item>
</style>
<style name="spinnerStyle">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/pink_white_dropdown</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
</style>
<style name="SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">#993399</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/pink_white_dropdown</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">10dip</item>
</style>
<style name="SpinnerDropDownItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">#993399</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@null</item>
    <!-- <item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item> -->
</style>
<style name="DropDownStyle">
    <item name="android:background">#FFF000</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">#FFF000</item>
</style>

<style name="checkboxStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
    <item name="android:textColor">#993399</item>
</style>
```