# Change spinner items color

Tags: android

I am developing an android app and in the activity I have three fields:
1. Mobile number
2. Spinner
3. Spinner

After user enters the mobile number I want to change the color of spinner items.

Can someone tell me how this can be done ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: show some sample image

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Text color Of spinner items coming after parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161125/change-text-color-of-spinner-items-coming-after-parsing)

Comment: @DavidJhons : I want to change the color of all the items of Spinner. The link you have shared is changing color for selected item only..

Answer (score 0):

You could listen to the onfocuschanged to do that, like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10627231/4714139). Alternatively, you could implement a textwatcher and listen to the ontextchanged event, like in [here](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/06/android-edittext-text-change-listener.htmlhttp://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/06/android-edittext-text-change-listener.html?m=1).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

    et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { 
              if(count>0)
              {
                    // Set color of spinner item here
              }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            Log.e("TextWatcherTest", "afterTextChanged:\t" +s.toString());
        }
    });
```