# Changing spinner arrow, Appcompat v21

Tags: android, spinner, styling, android-appcompat

i have activities which i themed with my custom theme, but for spinner i choosed to style it with Appcompat v21 but i got this :
[image]

**So how to change the Spinner arrow to be black or blue if is there a way ?**

i found this as similar question but doesn't have any answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28561105/add-custom-spinner-arrow
here is my spinner :

```
<Spinner
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

i used this to style the spinner:

```
 <style name="MyTheme.SpinnerAppTheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Spinner">
    </style>
```

this is how i use the adapter

```
   ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                getBaseContext(), R.array.listMedRes, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

i just want to theme the spinner , thanks alot

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you are using AppCompat-v21, you can take advantage of the new material design styles attributes:

**colorPrimary**: your app branding color for the app bar, applies to action bar

**colorPrimaryDark**: darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars

**colorAccent**: lets you define bright complement to the primary branding color. By default, this is the color applied to framework controls (via colorControlActivated)

**colorControlNormal**: color applied to framework controls in their normal state

**colorControlActivated**: applied to framework controls in their activated

Here is an example for you

**styles.xml**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/primary</item>
</style>
```

**colors.xml**

```
<resources>
    <color name="primary">#ff0000ff</color>
    <color name="primary_dark">#ff0000af</color>
    <color name="accent">#870000ff</color>
    <color name="white">#ffffffff</color>
</resources>
```

Here is how it looks

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: this worked using appcompat theme to the entire activity, is ther a way to use it only in spinner ?

Comment: one elegant solution there!

Comment: To response of @Charaf Eddine Mechalikh question about how to use the style directly to the spinner, refer to my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34542490/3940133

Answer (score 27):

Might be late but better late than never. To respond to your question: "Is there a way to use it only in spinner?". The answer is yes, refer to the code below.

Add this code to your theme or style file

```
<style name="customSpinnerTheme" parent="yourAppThemeThatUseAppCompat21">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#eaeaea</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#000000</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#000000</item>
</style>
```

Then in your XML that use spinner you can add this line

```
android:theme="@style/customSpinnerTheme"
```

e.g.

```
<Spinner
    android:theme="@style/customSpinnerTheme"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog" />
```

Comment: in is never too late to share knowledge , thank you ,may this will help others

Comment: How can I set the background color of the spinner within that style?

Comment: @TylerPfaff refer to this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703233/style-android-spinner

Answer (score 7):

There is a way to change your arrow color... actually it's not color you can change this image with blue color image.. 
create a xml file `myspinner_selector` in your drawable folder 
and paste

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item><layer-list>
        <item><shape>
                <gradient android:angle="90" android:endColor="#ffffff" android:startColor="#ffffff" android:type="linear" />

                <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#504a4b" />

                <corners android:radius="5dp" />

                <padding android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="3dp" />
            </shape></item>
        <item ><bitmap android:gravity="bottom|right" android:src="@drawable/blue_arrow" />   // you can use any other image here, instead of default_holo_dark_am
        </item>
      </layer-list></item>

 </selector>
```

blue_arrow is an image, and add this style in your style file

```
 <style name="spinner_style" >
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/myspinner_selector</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dp</item>

        </style>
```

finally add this style in your spinner

```
 <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/spinner_style"           

         />
```

it look like this. you need to customize  [image]

Answer (score 2):

look at below code.
create spinner_bg.xml under drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item><layer-list>
            <item><shape>
                    <gradient android:angle="270" android:centerColor="#d0d0d0" android:endColor="#c5c6c6" android:startColor="#dbdadb" android:type="linear" />
                    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#7a7a7a" />
                    <corners android:radius="1dp" />
                    <padding android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" />
                </shape></item>
            <item><bitmap android:gravity="center|right" android:src="@drawable/dropdown_icon_black" />
            </item>
        </layer-list></item>
</selector>
```

write down below code in styles.xml

```
<style name="spinner_style">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_bg</item>
</style>
```

Apply style to spinner

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    style="@style/spinner_style"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:overlapAnchor="false"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

use this image for spinner drawable
[image]

Answer (score 1):

you could tint it with the attribute tint color.

```
<Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
/>
```