# Android Spinner change arrow color

Tags: java, android, xml, spinner, drawable

I have seen questions about this previously but none seem to work for me.
I want to change the color of the material drop down, as seen [here](http://postimg.org/image/h0wao6kb1/)

I want to make the arrow black.
I have tried making a custom drawable and using that with dropDownSelector but it didn't show the arrow correctly. I have tried adding it as a style and it didn't work either.
Any ideas would be great.
Thanks

Comment: I shall be interested to see what other answers you get, this may be possible with themeing. However in my experience you get a more customizable and better result if you abandon spinner and create your own image with states and a custom dialogFragment and a listview.

Comment: set background image on spinner whatever you like arrow color

Comment: @MohitSuthar doing that just gives you a stretched version of the icon that goes across the whole view. Doesn't work

Comment: Have you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911287/change-colour-of-small-triangle-on-spinner-in-android

Comment: try also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135258/changing-spinner-arrow-appcompat-v21

Comment: @MohitSuthar the problem was my image wasn't saved as a 9patch and edited as one, once I did that setting the background worked. If you want to make an answer I'll set yours as the correct one :)

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem as well. But i had some focus problems, because Spinner was inside ScrollView. I have solved the issue by implementing ListPopupWindow.

[Here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2078060&seqNum=4) is great example how to implement ListPopupWindow :

Comment: Seems like a hacky way to fix a small issue :(

Comment: Yes, but this will work for 100%. I posted it because, it's easy to implement and works way better than Spinner, at least for my use case.

Comment: I solved it by using an arrow image and editing it as a 9patch, then setting it as the Spinner background. Thanks for the answer though