# Styling a spinner in android to change its appearance

Tags: android

How can I style an android spinner to make it look like this -

[image: Spinner Template]

PS: I want the spinner appearance to be changed not its label.

Comment: I want the spinner appearance to be changed not its label size and color.

Comment: `android:background="backgroundimage"` and `android:popupBackground="popupimage"`

Comment: Check this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703233/style-android-spinner

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/scale_10dp">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spnCatogary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/txt_14"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSpnCatogary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/left_margin_round_shape_edittext"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/down_arrow"
        android:hint="English"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
        android:padding="@dimen/scale_7dp"
        android:textColor="@color/hint_text_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/txt_14" />
</FrameLayout>
```

left_margin_round_shape_edittext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item>

    <shape android:shape="rectangle">

        <solid android:color="#E7E7E7" />

        <corners android:radius="4dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:left="2dp">

    <shape android:shape="rectangle">

        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

        <corners android:radius="2dp" />

        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#E7E7E7" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

also add image here

```
[![down_arrow][1]][1]
```

Comment: Can you share  android:background="@drawable/left_margin_round_shape_edittext"  file?

Comment: Aslo please send me that image android:drawableRight="@drawable/down_arrow"

Comment: @craziejunkie : i update here ypu check it and upvote.