# How to change the color of the selected item of a spinner

Tags: android, layout, styles, spinner, textcolor

how to change the text color of the spinner, the text which is on the left side of the dropdown button? ("Denmark" in the picure)

[image]

Comment: I don't know why all the down-votes -- this seems a reasonable question to me. I don't know the answer, but I know what is being asked. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703233/style-android-spinner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to try like this

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
   TextView selectedText = (TextView) parent.getChildAt(0);
   if (selectedText != null) {
      selectedText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
   }
}
```

Comment: works just fine :)

Comment: its fine for u?